# Can someone requests further modification after the revised deadline in an IEEE conference?

Tags: publications, phd, conference, paper-submission, review-articles

If one has an accepted paper in the conference and he already submitted the revised version. Suppose that the deadline for submitting the revised papers has been finished last week for example. Is it possible to send a mail to the conference in order to request some further changes? In other words, can this be acceptable by the IEEE conference?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Contact the program chairs immediately.** There is a moment in the publication process where changes are no longer possible, but this moment is not necessarily the deadline for revised papers.

Regarding the acceptability of such a request: Conference organizers are humans, too, so they will understand that people make errors and/or suboptimal choices. In addition, they might have an active interest in publishing the revised version: For example, a critical error that made it through the review process may reflect poorly on the conference and its organizers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am afraid that if I contact the program chairs, they reject my paper since I have an error in the text. what do you think? In fact what I want to do is just to add two very important words for more clarification and this can improve a lot the paper.

Comment: It depends on the error. If it completely changes the message of your paper, this *could* happen, but then you should still contact them, so you don't publish an incorrect paper. If your changes are only for clarification, then there is zero chance that your paper is rejected on that ground.

Comment: Yes my changes will only be for clarification! my theory and results are correct for 100%, but adding some words for clarification will be very interesting!

Comment: You need to communicate with the person who is in charge for managing the submission and reviewing process - normally, the program chair.

Comment: Okay, I contacted the program chair. I contacted the mail by which I have received the acceptation decision of my paper. I think I contacted the paper administration.

Comment: Sounds good. Good luck with the revised version!

Comment: The paper administration answered me that the the revised paper submission has passed and so they don't do exceptions. But this means that the moment in the publication process for changes is still possible. So I contacted one of the program chairs and I am waiting his answer. Hope that he will help me.

Comment: Contacting the program chairs is a good idea - they're in charge of the process, the "paper administration" is only executing orders.

Comment: Yes the program chairs accepted my request and so I have added my changes:)

Comment: Do you think they will be angry if I contact them again to add a little thing? This will be very weird I think no?

Comment: Angry I'm not sure, but it will surely come off a little weird/odd. At this point, I would leave the paper as it is.

Comment: Anyway I sent to them a very kind request and my last version paper in the attachment. I hope that they will accept again. I think the program chair for my conference are really very friendly and kind. I will keep you in touch

Comment: They told me it is too late. They started with the proceedings.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. But I think the paper is good as it is, otherwise the reviewers wouldn't have accepted it. Congratulations again!